# Not getting console of vm in kubevirt

Tags: kubernetes

I installed k3s and kubevirt on Fedora33 Server. I create a virtual machine named cirros but while getting console of vm I am facing issue while I can connect with ssh.

Comment: Please provide some reproducible steps, describing what exactly you do and what error you get.

Answer (score 0):

KubeVirt gives you access to the graphical and serial console.
But in order for SSH to work you need to manually enable it inside the quest - or via cloud-init.